# How to resolve INVALID_SESSION_ID error on fetching Tooling API data

Tags: apex, soql, callout, metadata-api, tooling-api

Using the **Tooling API** I need to fetch All Workflow rule Details. My below code **work perfectly** on the developer console Anonymous Window, but in LWC when I envoke the method with **@wire** shows me an error  '**This session is not valid for use with the REST API errorCode INVALID_SESSION_ID**'. What to do?

*Note: I assume that the Error is because tooling API runs in future when it gets the free salesforce Resource and in future, Salesforce is not able to identify the Session-Id even if the same user is logged in. I don't know I am right or wrong?*

**My syntax**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static  Map<String, Object> GetWorkflowRuleList(String userId)
    {

        if(String.isEmpty(userId))
        {

            return null;
        }

        String sToken=UserInfo.getSessionId();        
        Map<String, Object> flowJsonData = new Map<String, Object>();
        String body = null;


        try{        
            
            String toolingSOQL='/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,Name,TableEnumOrId,createdById,lastModifiedById+From+WorkflowRule';
            String baseURL=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            String endPoint=baseURL+toolingSOQL;
    
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
            hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sToken);
            hr.setTimeout(60000);
            hr.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            hr.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            hr.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse r = h.send(hr);

            if(r.getStatusCode() == 200){
                body= r.getBody();                
            } else {
                throw new CalloutException(r.getBody());
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }        

        if(!String.isBlank(body)){
            flowJsonData = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
            System.debug('ResponseBody:::'+flowJsonData);
        }
        if(!flowJsonData.isEmpty()){
            return flowJsonData;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How to avoid INVALID_SESSION_ID error? Without using tooling API is there any way to fetch detailed data for workflow rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the visualforce page session to access tooling ID

Create a visualforce page as shown below,

```
<apex:page contentType="application/json"> {!$Api.Session_ID} </apex:page>
```

Controller to fetch the session ID

```
public inherited sharing class SessionHelper { 

   public static String getSessionId()  {
     return Test.isRunningTest() ? '' :  Page.session.getContent().toString().trim(); 
   }
  }
```

You can obtain the session using `SessionHelper.getSessionId()`

Comment: thanks it's worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use named credentials for making this call. The session id in LWC cannot be used for accessing API by design due to security considerations.

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm#apex_api_calls